# What is the difference between 00000 and 99999 in masked textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, kendo-ui, maskedtextbox

When I try to use a masked textbox in my project, I saw that `00000` and `99999` give the same result of `_____` in my masked textbox.

Is 0 and 9 is the same in a mask of my masked textbox? If any difference: what are all that?

Please explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of the [Mask property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx):

```
Masking element     Description
---------------     -----------
0                   Digit, required.This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.
9                   Digit or space, optional.
```

They're not the same, but every piece of the mask that is not a literal character to be included (like date or time separators or the dots in an IP address) will become an underscore to indicate that they are a place to enter stuff.

Answer (score 4):

> 0   Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.
>
> 9   Digit or space, optional.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Answer (score 0):

000000 and 999999 has give the same **__** in our WinForm. Don't Confuse. Its all refer the Same Digit. But You can use 0 is a must enter values like 00-00-0000 as date.

And 9 is ref Optional. like 999 as _96.

If you want use 0 and 9 as number in Masked Textbox,.. you can use \ before.